# Hovering over a link in a Flash file - browser highlighting

Tags: html, browser, flash

Is there any way of showing a link's destination from a swf in the browser? The answer might be a simple no.

Hard to explain, so I have attached a screenshot that makes it clearer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/148/tn_14827.html , it seems possible to change the status bar of the browser from flash. As far as I know you still need to do this by hand for a button.

An other way is to use JavaScript calls from Flash (see http://naarvoren.nl/artikel/flash_en_javascript/deploy/basic_demo.html for a demo).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use ExternalInterface to call javascript that changes the "window.status" but you would have to create a MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT event listeneres on every link :)